# What git remote add ssh does?

Tags: git

In the project I'm working on, there is a shell wrapper for git clone as:

```
  $git clone -b $branch git://$host/$path $ROOT/$repo
  (cd $ROOT/$repo && $git remote add ssh git@$host:$path)
```

I wonder why they do 'git remote add' again after 'git clone'? And what this 'git remote add' command actually does?

Comment: Try reading some documentation: `git help remote`. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Comment: it adds the remote repository under the alias `ssh` to the local clone. maybe they need this for some deploy or testing scripts, this is very project specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Git docs:

> Remote repositories are versions of your project that are hosted on
>   the Internet or network somewhere. You can have several of them, each
>   of which generally is either read-only or read/write for you.

When you run `git remote add <remote-name> <repository-name>` you're adding a remote repository that you can push/pull from.

This is especially useful if you've begun a Git repo on your local machine and would like to push it to a site like GitHub later. For that you'd create a repository on Github and then write something like `git remote add origin <github-url>` then you'll be able to push/pull on that repo.

For more information on working with remotes be sure to check out http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html